# CSS table td vertical-align text-top

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have problem with vertical-align to text-top on tables

I have globally set at table `td` to `vertical-align: middle`.

Now I need to change **only one** `td` to `vertical-align: text-top`

The problem is, that all variant that I tested set `vertical-align:text-top` are shown as **top** only

("xxxx" in image is not at same line as "yyyy")

Only one variant is working as `text-top`, and that is change globally style of all `td` (I don't want this, I need to change **only one** `td`)

SEE IMAGES

Setting as local style is shown as **top**
[local style http://aukro.svecpetr.com/style.png](http://aukro.svecpetr.com/style.png)

Setting as class is shown as **top**
[local style http://aukro.svecpetr.com/class.png](http://aukro.svecpetr.com/class.png)

Changing global `td` has the right effect of **text-top**
[local style http://aukro.svecpetr.com/global-style.png](http://aukro.svecpetr.com/global-style.png)

**EXAMPLE** you could find at
https://zbozimat.cz/test.php

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Can you put your code **[here](http://jsFiddle.net)**?

Comment: I put example here https://zbozimat.cz/test.php

Comment: They *are* aligned.  The text in your first cell is aligned with the tallest element in your second cell, which is the button.  You can't align the text to the top of something that is center aligned to something else like that.

Comment: @user5332 Do you mean that you want the `xxxx` to be set as `text-top` and the `yyyy` leave at the bottom? In that case, why don't you create 2 CSS rules? First one for the top and the second for the bottom. Put a `td class="top-align"` and `td class="bottom-align"`. `Class` name does not make any difference (like your own language) but make sure is Utf chars.

Answer (score 38):

Add this for div:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

And this for input:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

Comment: Short and simple, this is a good answere. I din't need display tag tho

Answer (score 4):

It is also possible to set the attr style on your td

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;">
```